# Model legal shift constraints

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, constraints, operations-research, binary-programming

I need your help.
My decision variable $b_{fds}$ indicates whether a fireman $f$ works shift $s$ on day $d$. I need two constraints:

a) No more than 5 consecutive working
days

b) At least 2 consecutive days off after a
working period

c) At least 2 consecutive working days

How would I model those constraints in a linear way?

Comment: Can a fireman work more than one shift per day?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. Nope only one per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each fireman works at most one shift per day, you can think of $\sum_s b_{f,d,s}$ as a binary variable.  You can derive linear constraints somewhat automatically by rewriting the logical propositions in conjunctive normal form.

For part a), disallow $6$ shifts in each consecutive $6$-day interval:
$$
\lnot \left(\sum_s b_{f,d,s} \land \sum_s b_{f,d+1,s} \land \dots \land \sum_s b_{f,d+5,s}\right) \\
\lnot \sum_s b_{f,d,s} \lor \lnot \sum_s b_{f,d+1,s} \lor \dots \lor \lnot \sum_s b_{f,d+5,s} \\
\left(1-\sum_s b_{f,d,s}\right)+\left(1-\sum_s b_{f,d+1,s}\right)+\dots+\left(1-\sum_s b_{f,d+5,s}\right)\ge 1 \\
\sum_s (b_{f,d,s} + b_{f,d+1,s} + \dots + b_{f,d+5,s}) \le 5
$$

Part b) is similar, except that you want to avoid the work pattern $101$ instead of $111111$:
$$
\lnot \left(\sum_s b_{f,d,s} \land \lnot \sum_s b_{f,d+1,s} \land \sum_s b_{f,d+2,s}\right) \\
\lnot \sum_s b_{f,d,s} \lor \sum_s b_{f,d+1,s} \lor \lnot \sum_s b_{f,d+2,s} \\
\left(1-\sum_s b_{f,d,s}\right) + \sum_s b_{f,d+1,s} + \left(1-\sum_s b_{f,d+2,s}\right) \ge 1 \\
\sum_s \left(b_{f,d,s} - b_{f,d+1,s} + b_{f,d+2,s}\right) \le 1
$$

For part c), introduce a new binary variable $z_{f,d}$ to indicate whether fireman $f$ works on days $d$ and $d+1$, and impose
\begin{align}
\sum_d z_{f,d} &\ge 1 \\
z_{f,d} &\le \sum_s b_{f,d,s} \\
z_{f,d} &\le \sum_s b_{f,d+1,s}
\end{align}
A weaker but more compact formulation replaces the last two constraints with their aggregation
$$2z_{f,d} \le \sum_s \left(b_{f,d,s} + b_{f,d+1,s}\right)$$

Comment: Would you mind also sharing the linear form for b) since I am not really familiar with logical proposition

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Suppose $y_{fd}$ indicates whether a fireman works on day $d$. Would this be a correct formulation of a more generalised version, where $C$ represents the number of days off required?   $\sum_{h=d}^{d+C}y_{fh}\ge 1~~~~\forall f\in F, d\in \{1,\ldots,D-C\} $

Comment: What you proposed enforces that each fireman *works* at least one day in every consecutive $(C+1)$-day interval.  If I understand correctly, you want $1-y_{fh}$ instead of $y_{fh}$.

Comment: Regarding c). What would you propose? And how do I formulate b) for a unknown number, to be always satisfied? That would be my last request. I promise

Comment: For a generalization to b), see https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/set-null-the-next-set-of-n-values/9820#9820

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by working period you mean atmost 3 day, you may try
$\sum_s (b_{f,s,d}+b_{f,s,d+1}) \le \sum_s (3b_{f,s,d-1} - \sum_{k=d-1}^{d-3}b_{f,s,k}) \ \ \forall d,f$